# How to make a Text Box maximum and minimum

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

I can't figure out how to make a textbox only able to show like numbers between 1-1000.
Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

```
    private void tbInvoerEuros1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch !=46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, I thought so too but then I can't use 1000. But thank you for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to make a textbox only able to show like numbers between 1-1000. Can someone help me with this?

The easiest way is to switch to a NumericUpDown control, which has Minimum, Maximum, and Interval, and Decimals properties.  You can also have scroll buttons and allow the user to type in the values, which are automatically validated.

Since you must use a textbox here is one way that handles the Validating event and notifies the user of invalid input and returns the focus back to the textbox.

```
    private void TextBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        double input;
        if(double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out input))
        {
            if(input < 1 || input > 1000)
                e.Cancel = true;
            else
                e.Cancel = false;
        }
        else
            e.Cancel = true;
        if(e.Cancel)
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input!");
    }
```

To create and register the handler, click on the events icon in the property grid for the textbox.  Double-Click `Validating` and use this code inside the stub that gets written.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm only allowed to use a textbox for this exercise.

Comment: I added more code for you to look at.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot man it was the solution for me!